# Is it possible to use while or any arbitrary iterator with map?

Tags: ruby, iterator

```
i = 0

while i < 10 do
  i += 1
end
```

Is there a way to make this emit the values [1..10]?

For example:

```
ary = while (i < 10).map do
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to use a while or other loop construct with map.

Comment: Sure, but why? What's the problem you're trying to solve? Why do you have to deal with `while` in the first place? I'm asking because there's probably a better way to solve this.

Comment: Because I have run into some problems that require a while construct and create an array. Instead of initializing the array before the while and mutating it, this approach is cleaner and more Rubyish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to make this emit the values?
>   I want to use `while` [...]

I doubt I follow why you want to use `while` in ruby in general, but yes, this is possible if you wrap `while` into an `Enumerator` instance.

```rb
Enumerator.new do |y|
  i = 0
  while i < 10 do
    i += 1
    y << i
  end
end.map { |i| i ** 2 }
#⇒ [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer, no you cannot. `while` is not a typical method and so the `while (i < 10).map do .. end` syntax is not even recognized.

However if you look at the docs for [`Enumerator::Lazy`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html) you will see something quite similar:

```
(1..Float::INFINITY).lazy.filter_map{|i| i*i if i.even?}.first(5)
    # => [4, 16, 36, 64, 100]
```

In your case it could be

```
(1..Float::INFINITY).lazy.take_while { |x| x < 10 }.map {|i| i }.to_a
    # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Although this is super overcomplicated for the simple use-case you have shown. Normally I would just do `1.upto(10).map { |i| ... }`

Comment: You can use `(1..)` instead of `(1..Float::INFINITY)` since Ruby 2.6.0.

Answer (score 2):

```
p [*1..10]
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

If you want to iterate then

```
(1..10).each do |num|
  p num
end
```

Comment: `[*1..10].each` is a waste (unless you are actually using the return value of `each`); `(1..10).each` (or `1.upto(10).each`) would be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

A common approach is to move the loop into its own method which *yields* each value to a block, or returns an enumerator if no block is given: (using [`enum_for`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Object.html#method-i-enum_for))

```
def my_method
  return enum_for(__method__) unless block_given?

  i = 0
  while i < 10 do
    i += 1
    yield i
  end
end
```

This is very similar to [Aleksei Matiushkin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59386171/477037) and the usage is comparable:

```
my_method
#=> #<Enumerator: main:my_method>

my_method do |i|
  # do something with i
end

my_method.map { |i| i * 2 }
#=> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a range:

```
(1..10).map { |n| n*2 }
=> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
```

Comment: I want to use `while` or other construct. `while i < 10 do` is just the reduced example.

Comment: I see. In that case, no, you can't, at least not directly. See the `Enumerator` answers above for alternatives.